# Notepad++ syntax highlighting: How to declare `number` and `boolean` as non-keywords for JavaScript?

Tags: notepad++

By default `number` and `boolean` seem to be considered keywords if you switch to "language -> JavaScript" in Notepad++ (actually I do not even know why) and therefore they are specially highlighted.
What is the simplest way (using UDL or whatever) to declare them as non-keywords so that Notepad++ does not specially highlight them any longer in JavaScript mode?

[EDIT] Okay, I found out that at least for `number` it is quite easy - you can change your theme specific style configuration: Go to **Settings > Style Configurator** and select **Language**: **JavaScript** and **Style**: **Keyword** then under **User-defined keywords** you can remove `number`. But unfortunately `boolean` is added under **Default keywords** and you cannot edit those default keywords. What can I do?

Comment: Instead of giving an answer in the question, you'd better add an answer and accept it if you think it solves your problem.

Comment: It only answers half of the question ... the part with `boolean` is still open.

Comment: [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) **is** a keyword in Javascript. SSee also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#boolean_type

Comment: Thanks a lot Toto - you're right: `boolean` is indeed a keyword in JavaScript (I didn't know that) - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp
Could you please write your sentence as answer so I can accept it and you'll get your well earned reputation credit for it?

Comment: I didn't answer the question, **you** did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `number` it turned out to be quite easy - you can change your theme specific style configuration: Go to **Settings > Style Configurator** and select **Language: JavaScript** and **Style: Keyword** then under **User-defined keywords** you can remove `number`.

As for the word `boolean` it turned out that `boolean` (in contrast to `number`) is (or was) indeed a keyword in JavaScript (see: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) - thanks a lot to Toto for that clarification (see comments above).
To be more precise is was a "future reserved word" in JavaScript versions before ECMAScript5 (see here: Section "Removed Reserved Words" in https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp and https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ReservedWord). In modern JavaScript `boolean` is not a reserved word any longer.